# jQuery animate changing text infinite loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, infinite-loop, document-ready

I'm trying to create a text change animation based on fade-out - change text - fade-in concept that will run as an infinite loop, circling 3 different texts with 2 second pauses inbetween.

I have this jQuery code in my Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function changeText(){
    $(this).find("#changeText").delay(2000).animate({opacity:0},function(){
        $(this).text("foo").animate({opacity:1},function(){
            $(this).delay(2000).animate({opacity:0},function(){
                $(this).text("bar").animate({opacity:1}, function(){

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

which does what it's supposed to, but, of course, only once. I can't seem to get it to work as a loop no matter what I do. I have browsed a lot of similar Stack Overflow questions, but none seem to have solved my problem.

I tried setInterval, window.function, for loop and a few other soltuions, and they either throw an error about too much recursion or crash my browser or don't work at all. Either it's not even supposed to work that way or I am not doing something right.

This is the HTML that I'm trying to change:

```
<div class="container"><span id="changeText">blah</span></div>
```

Comment: Could you post the html as well ? Just a script code would make things harder to understand.

Comment: I forgot to add it, thanks @DinoMyte. It's edited now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using '`this`' reference at the starting of your code, but it's missing the context to the element it's pointing to. Also, since you have the element with the id '`changeText`', you can simply target it directly in your selector.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#changeText").delay(2000).animate(
    {opacity:0 },function(){
       $(this).text("foo").animate({opacity:1},function(){
        $(this).delay(2000).animate({opacity:0},function(){
            $(this).text("bar").animate({opacity:1}, function(){
            });
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/q1o2f5jx/

EDIT :

To make improvement in the code, add the text in the array and increment the index on setInterval.

```
var textArray = ["foo","bar","blah1","blah2"];
var index = 0;
setInterval(function(){        
$("#changeText").animate({
opacity:0
},function()
{
   if(textArray.length > index) {
   $(this).text(textArray[index]).animate({opacity:1})
   index++; 
   }
   else
   index = 0;
});
},2000);
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/q1o2f5jx/2/

Comment: Now I see I made a mistake with 'this' reference. For some reason it worked with it aswell, but your answer didn't really help me out with the repetition that I am trying to make...

Comment: Didn't realize you were asking for improvement. Follow the edit section.

Comment: Well, not exactly. I was just trying to repeat the animations over and over again. In the meantime I have found a solution myself. Thanks alot anyway!

Comment: Just realised you gave me a correct, working solution to this. I was too tired and distracted to see it that day and I thought it didn't work as I wanted it to. Marked it as accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I must be stupid, the solution was too simple for me to see it. I even tryed it, but I must have written something wrong which made it not work. All this time I was trying to re-call the function inside the '$(document).ready' scope from outside the scope, which is close to impossible, but I actually don't need to do it.

I just created a normal JavaScript function with jQuery inside it which is being called once outside the function, and every re-call is being made from the last .animate() callback.

```
function changeText(){
    $("#changeText").delay(2000).animate({opacity:0},function(){
        $(this).text("foo").animate({opacity:1},function(){
            $(this).delay(2000).animate({opacity:0},function(){
                $(this).text("bar").animate({opacity:1},function(){
                    $(this).delay(2000).animate({opacity:0},function(){
                        $(this).text("blah").animate({opacity:1},function(){
                            changeText();                           
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
};

changeText();
```